# Calling function in ViewController but parameters seems wrong

Tags: ios, swift, generics

I created a custom class to save a array of Products in NSUserDefaults, but when I will test in my ViewController, I always get this using the autocomplete from Xcode 7.1

[image: function]

The function *saveToFile* or *loadFromFile* always shows `self: DataFile` as unique parameter.

This is my DataFile class

```
import Foundation

class DataFile {
    let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

    func saveToFile<T>(object: [T], key: String) -> String {
        let encodedData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(object as! AnyObject)

        self.userDefaults.setObject(encodedData, forKey: key)
        self.userDefaults.synchronize()

        return "oi"
    }

    func loadFromFile<T>(key: String) -> [T]? {
        let decoded = self.userDefaults.objectForKey(key) as! NSData

        if let decodedProducts = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(decoded) as? [T] {
            return decodedProducts
        }

        return nil
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you

Comment: You forgot to pass () when calling. Try like this DataFile().saveToFile(object, key:  String)

DataFile().loadFromFile(String)

Comment: If you want to call it without it you need to declare your method as class func

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your funcs are not static function, so, you must create object to use these functions.

```
let xxx = DataFile()
xxx.loadFromFile(<#T##key: String##String#>)
```